# placefigure left to paragraph inside columnset in ConTeXt

Tags: context-mkiv

I would like to have a dropcap which is an image and use it's actual size (rather small) instead of specifying a number of lines (as lettrine does). I came up with a somewhat working solution using \placefigure but this fails to work inside a columnset environment (the image is centered above the text). Simple MWE follows.

```
\definecolumnset[TwoColumns][n=2]

\starttext

\startcolumnset [TwoColumns]

\placefigure[left, force, none]{}{\externalfigure[cow]}
First paragraph.

\input tufte

\stopcolumnset

\stoptext
```

Any idea on what I did wrong ? As well, it is guaranteed that the image will be before the text ?